# How to call a dot net asssembly / namespace in XSLT

Tags: .net, xslt

I am writing dot net code within my XSLT. It gives me below error when I call any namespace OR write "using" directive within XSLT.

Error-
"Could not recognize 'com.myassembly' "

Is it possible to use any assembly within xslt?

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for detailed information that solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, and you need to use [extension objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf741884.aspx) - you will have to pass these in to the xslt processor before you can use them in the xsl file.

See the examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfktf882.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at examples like the following:

- [Implementing Paging and XSLT Extensions Using XSLT in .NET - Part 1](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/031105.htm)
- [Implementing Paging and XSLT Extensions Using XSLT in .NET - Part 2](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/031112.htm)
- [Extending XSLT with JScript, C#, and Visual Basic .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302079.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Read about:

[**`<msxsl:using>`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256167.aspx)

[**`<msxsl:assembly>`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256188(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: I have used the below code-

<msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="callCode">
<msxsl:using namespace="global::com.myassembly.crs.app.services.contentTypes"/>

 <![CDATA[  
  public int GetValue()

    {

    Test1 t = new Test1();

    return t.GetValue();

    }

    ]]>
  </msxsl:script>

Get this error-
**The type or namespace name 'com' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)**

Comment: @contactkx: according to source linked by Dimitre, you need to reference the assembly too.