# dot net namespace error in XSLT 2.0

Tags: .net, xslt

I get below error on calling dot net code within my XSLT file

**error: The type or namespace name 'com' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?)**

This is code snippet-

```
<msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="callCode">
<msxsl:using namespace="global::com.myassembly.crs.app.services.contentTypes"/>

<![CDATA[

public int GetValue()

{

Test1 t = new Test1();

return t.GetValue();

}

]]>
</msxsl:script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call a dot net asssembly / namespace in XSLT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372205/how-to-call-a-dot-net-asssembly-namespace-in-xslt)

Answer (score 0):

**You need to specify an assembly reference**.

Use the **[`<msxsl:assembly>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256188%28VS.80%29.aspx)** extension element for that.